# Jquery, plugin is not identified/called

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am trying to write my custom plugin(and figure our how they work), for sorting the datable.
The issue is that the plugin is not getting identified/called, when I set sType in the data-table initialization.

I am just making the first column as sortable.

The following is the code:

The plugin file

```
/**
 * Custom sort file name jquery.ui.customsort.js
 */

(function($) {
  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-asc']  = function(x,y) {
     return ((x < y) ? -1 : ((x > y) ?  1 : 0));
  };
  jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['string-case-desc'] = function(x,y) {
      return ((x < y) ?  1 : ((x > y) ? -1 : 0));
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The java script that initializes the datable is:

```
/**
 * Initialization the data table
 */

  var oSortTable=null;
  $(function() {

/*Creating the html for the table with id 'sort_table'*/
var sorttablehtml = "<table id='sort_table'><thead><tr><th>FirstName</th>  <th>FamilyName</th></tr></thead><tbody>";
sorttablehtml +='<tr class="contactnamedetail"><td>New York</td><td>United States</td></tr>';
sorttablehtml +='<tr class="contactnamedetail"><td>Paris</td><td>Paris</td></tr>';
sorttablehtml +='<tr class="contactnamedetail"><td>Sydney</td><td>Australia</td></tr>';
sorttablehtml +='<tr class="contactnamedetail"><td>Berlin</td><td>Germany</td></tr>';
sorttablehtml +="</tbody></table>"; 


$('#sortingtable').html(sorttablehtml);
/*converting the table to datatable*/
oSortTable=$('#sort_table').dataTable({
      "aoColumns": [ 
                    { "sType": "string-case"},
                    { "bSortable": false }//Disable sorting on this column

                    ]
  });
});
```

I am missing out on something which I am not able to figure out.
Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Errors in the console are:

```
 Timestamp: 3/7/2013 12:52:11 PM
 Error: TypeError: jQuery.fn.dataTableExt is undefined
 Source File: http://myorg:8080/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.customsort.js
 Line: 6

 Timestamp: 3/7/2013 12:55:33 PM
 Error: TypeError: oCol is undefined
 Source File: http://myorg:8080/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js
 Line: 784
```

Order of the files getting is:

```
<!-- Jquery files used for various plugins and widgets -->
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/themes /base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/demos /demos.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/js/jquery- 1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development- bundle/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development- bundle/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.tabs.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.effects.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.effects.fade.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.jeditable.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.editable.js"></script>


<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/css/demo_page.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/css/demo_table_jui.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/css/demo_table.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller.css" rel="Stylesheet" />
<link type="text/css" href="/jqueryproject/javascript/datatables/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="Stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.customsort.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/jquery/development-bundle/ui/jquery.ui.fixedwidth.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/custom/jqueryproject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="/jqueryproject/javascript/custom /sortingtable.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is the error being reported to the console please?

Comment: Edited the errors that appear in the console. jQuery.fn.dataTableExt is undefined, may be I am missing some file,,, but which one will it be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what order are you loading your external files?

**Are you adding your plugin *prior* to the dataTables .js file**? If so, that could be the cause of the error.

A similar issue has come up before on the datatables forum: 
http://www.datatables.net/forums/discussion/9661/.fn.datatableext-is-undefined/p1

Also, I have attempted to create a fiddle out of your code sample, 
and have not found any problems.

http://jsfiddle.net/r4FBQ/

If you view the frame source for the HTML of the fiddle, you should see how the plugin code comes after the dataTables js file.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
 // your plugin code...
</script>
```

Comment: I did change the order and then the first error is gone, but the second one remains: Error: TypeError: oCol is undefined, I have edited the original post with the order of the files getting loaded.

Comment: Ok, It has worked now, for some reason the cache was not getting cleared, even when I tried couple of time. After fixing the order of import, clean the cache, and its working. Thanks for the answer.